# Chrome Driver Options to Open Default Browser and not a new Window Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am Trying to Open the chrome in a configuration where all the extensions as well as in logged-in state.

I came across an answer to remove default from the chrome driver Options Module. However, when I added this and tried to execute the program runs Opens a new window with everything enabled, but it does not proceed to open the URL specified and stays at starting page.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
options=Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\aman krishna\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\aman krishna\Desktop\\New folder (3)\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

In this code a new window opens but does not search for www.google.com
After some time an error message is displayed i.e

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aman krishna/PycharmProjects/untitled9/beautifoulsoup.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\aman krishna\Desktop\\New folder (3)\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Users\aman krishna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\aman krishna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\aman krishna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\aman krishna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\aman krishna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Comment: Update your version of chromedriver to the latest version. Also make sure chrome and selenium are up to date.

Comment: updated every driver to its latest version. Still facing the same issue.